# Oracle Delete multiple columns (not a drop)

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

Dears,

I am trying to delete multiple columns values in an oracle table, I am running the below script but it seems that it is not working (although it did in SQL server).

```
DELETE a.mobile_num ,
                    a.price_list,
                    a.cust_segment,
                    a.classification,
                    a.region,
                    a.district,
                    a.localty,
                    a.dsl_install_dt,
                    a.dsl_oper_status,
                    a.fl_install_dt,
                    a.fl_status,
                    a.oper_status_cd
                    From mkt_wl_history_2 a;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete column values in Oracle, you can delete entire rows. If I understand correctly you are trying to set these values to NULL.

In this case you can use the following statement.

```
UPDATE mkt_wl_history_2                 
SET price_list=NULL,
    cust_segment=NULL,
    classification=NULL,
    region=NULL,
    district=NULL,
    localty=NULL,
    dsl_install_dt=NULL,
    dsl_oper_status=NULL,
    fl_install_dt=NULL,
    fl_status=NULL,
    oper_status_cd=NULL
```

Also, I assume you have to do this for all rows in your table. If not then please apply an appropriate where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use queries similar to this to set all values of a column to the default value:

`UPDATE mtk_wl_history_2 SET mobile_num = DEFAULT`